# Throwing this error message "Error -1 - SQL connection failed." when trying to connect SQL server from Microsoft Azure's Database Migration Services

Tags: sql-server, azure

We tried to do one poc which meets our upcoming requirement in my personal Laptop. The requirement is migrating the on premise sql database into azure sql database.

The screen shot of error is,
[Connection error message and description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NmHZ.png)

Below are steps which we have done.

Step1: 
We have created a sql database in azure portal. The server name is like sundar64599.database.windows.net
The Screenshot is here, [Sql database in azure poral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxluD.png)

Stpe2:
Then We have done the assessments and created the migration project in Data Migration Assistant tool and we deployed it successfully.

Step 3:
Then we created a Database Migration Services and tried to create a migration project.
Here we entered the source server details to connect and it throws the error as mentioned added the screenshot above.

And also we tried the below to resolve this connect issue.
1. In sql server confuguration management, 
   a. We restarted the sql server and tried to connect. But it fails. The screenshot is [Sql server restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkJgt.png)
   b. Then we had set the TCP port as 1433 and dynamic port as 50313 and tried to connect. But it fails. The Screenshot is, [Tcp with dynamic port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRkE8.png)
   c. Then we had set the TCP port as 1433 and dynamic port as empty and tried to connect. But it fails. The screenshot is, [Tcp empty dynamic port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhLTI.png)
2. In Sql database of azure portal, we checked the client ip and added the exact ip and tried. Even it fails. The Screenshot is, [Firewall ip settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Jjw.png)

Please add your suggestions to resolve this connection issue.

Thanks in advance,
Samidurai Tamilmani

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) or Public IP of the source server as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-to-azure-sql#specify-source-details). The way you are providing the source server will work in the local network but not from outside, which is required by the Azure Migration services.
So make sure that your source server is available from the internet. You can have a look at the complete steps here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-to-azure-sql

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yogi. We tried with FQDN and public IP address too. But still it was throwing the same error.